# Как правильно работать с api? Discord бот

Tags: c++, api, curl, discord

Начал учить программирование, а именно C++, создавая бота для Discord (C++ / libcurl).
Суть проблемы в том, что посылать запрос я научился, но вот что делать с полученным json и как его парсить?
Если не сложно, можете написать порядок действий для работы с api (отправка запроса и т.д)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Полученный json нужно парсить. Да, это можно попробовать сделать прям ручками, используя функции find и подобные, но не для того, в json присылается.

Есть чудесная библиотека https://github.com/nlohmann/json , которая как раз позволит все это распарсить и удобно почитать. Библиотека является "header only" - то есть, можно просто добавить один заголовочный файл и готово.

На странице есть куча примеров, как ее использовать.

P.S. Еще раз - то, что json получается через libcurl от discord никак не влияет на то, как его парсить, если он уже есть в виде строки.